# Match a values greater than 2000 using Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

i need a regular Expression that is True for inputs above 2000:

```
for (int i = 1998; i < 10001; i++)
{
    String s = Integer.toString(i);

    // Above Range 2000 to 9999

    System.out.print(i+"\t");

    System.out.println(s.matches("[^1]?[0-9]{1,3}"));
}
```

Comment: Why you don't test the integer directly?

Comment: You need an if statement, not a regex.

Comment: Actually I need to split it from  a SET of 24 Character  line

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just be using integer comparison, but just for fun here's the regex:

```
/(\d{5,}|[2-9](?=\d*[1-9])\d{3})/g
```

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/xH4mZ8/2)

Comment: This works in *nearly* all cases, as long as you aren't leading your numbers with `0`s - aka it'll match 00003.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract from a string only integers greater than 2000, two ways are possible.

It is note always simple to take in account mathematical considerations within a regex pattern since a regex pattern is build in a character logic. So you can simply extract all integers with `[0-9]+` or `[1-9][0-9]*`, cast the results to integers and test each of them with an if statement.

You can do it directly with the pattern, but you need to carefuly limit the impact on performance avoiding a giant alternation and failing branches. This is the way you can do this:

```
[3-9][0-9]{3,} 
|
2         
(?:
    [1-9][0-9]{2,}
  |
    0
    (?:
        [1-9][0-9]+
      |
        0 (?: [1-9][0-9]* | 0 [0-9]+)
    )
)
|
1 [0-9]{4,}
```

note: to allow `2000`, remove all the second main alternative and change the first to `[2-9][0-9]{3,}`

The main interest of this pattern is that once the regex engine enters in a branch it is always in the good one and has no other branch to test whatever the result (succeed or fail). Note that the three main branches are sorted by probability order, one more time to limit the engine work.

It is possible to improve it more (must be tested) if you enclose all in non capturing group and you check before with a lookahead if the current tested character is a digit. This improvement allows to skip quickly all characters of the string that are not a digit without to test the three branches of the main alternation.

```
(?=[1-9])(?:pattern)
```

that gives:

```
(?=[1-9])(?:[3-9][0-9]{3,}|2(?:[1-9][0-9]{2,}|0(?:[1-9][0-9]+|0(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0[0-9]+)))|1[0-9]{4,})
```

Comment: @DevonParsons: indeed, it is corrected now. The pattern is not designed to be short, it is designed to be efficient.